# npx react-native run-ios returns "error No simulator available with name IPhone 15"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-cli, xcode15

I have run `xcrun simctl list devices` I see:

```
== Devices ==
-- iOS 17.0 --
    iPhone Xs (DAD4BA79-A1FA-497F-B770-63FE2481A89D) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone SE (3rd generation) (485CA3EB-AACE-4293-8262-9304662F8E91) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 14 (91C014D1-4343-42D3-AA87-9F40D7CD3CE5) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 14 Plus (C7F8D92A-E751-409F-B899-DA95BE543136) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 14 Pro (529916F3-D9DB-4BD2-8AE5-DA84F1AFDE2B) (Shutdown) 
    Test Iphone (153CB498-DD6B-4B7B-8F6B-12D96CF765E5) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 14 Pro Max (BA1AE5FC-ACA9-4E33-B69F-684512F61C47) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 15 (1235BB71-7ADC-4288-93A6-ED093E26BFBB) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 15 Plus (93DA3429-954F-4865-A864-D4FA6B2FE609) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 15 Pro (833C4066-403E-456E-95C3-9CF4114A23AA) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 15 Pro Max (E348CF8A-3409-45DE-B5CA-6FF1DCD9EE76) (Shutdown) 
    iPad Air (5th generation) (33B54F06-5A05-4D6A-80B8-DF21401F6E79) (Shutdown) 
    iPad (10th generation) (2FCDC922-6DB9-4C9F-9B55-EF430338E04F) (Shutdown) 
    iPad mini (6th generation) (B2DFF23D-F47D-4EB5-96D7-81E956D83C81) (Shutdown) 
    iPad Pro (11-inch) (4th generation) (AA71E66E-09A8-4718-A392-0753CFE1E7C3) (Shutdown) 
    iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (6th generation) (3565DB49-3206-4C2C-A40F-577319ADE25E) (Shutdown) 
-- iOS 17.0 --
```

This only started happening after I updated from xcode 14.x to 15 and IOS Simulators from 16.x to 17.0. I can run the app fine using the xcode build button. I have tried specifying a phone UDID, same error.

I am using react-native 0.70.6 and react 18.1.0. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling xcode. I have deleted node modules and pods and reinstalled them. I have cleaned build folders and rebuilt. Nothing.

Comment: Have you tried adding an iPhone emulator with the name `IPhone 15` because when i got this error, simply adding the emulator with that name fixed it for me.

Comment: Kinda, an emulator with that name already does exist so I added an emulator with the name "test" and tried with --simulator Test Iphone and it still didn't work

Comment: Try to add an emulator with the actual name `IPhone 15` the casing has to be the same.

Comment: Look at the list of emulators, there already is one.

Comment: Yes with the name `iPhone 15`, not `IPhone 15` with a capital I. Your casing is not correct. Try this first.

Comment: Great catch, but sadly same issue. `error No simulator available with name "IPhone 15".`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, I had a problem with XCode Version 15.1 and I had to downgrade it to the XCode Version 15.0. But after that, I still received `"error No simulator available with name IPhone 15"`. So the solution was to go to `XCode -> Settings -> Platform` and delete extra Simulator SDK for IOS 17.1. In the attached image I already deleted the extra SDK but in your case, you might an extra `IOS Simulator 17.1` which you need to delete.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8BP1.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solved my problem, never saw this answer anywhere else, thank you so much. I have been manually building in XCode for months now. I really appreciate it, this solved my issue immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following to the scripts part of the package.json:

> "ios-15": "react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 15'",

> "ios-14": "react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 14'",

and run with the following command for iPhone 14 or 15 respectively:

> npm run ios-15
> or
> npm run ios-14

Make sure to check ',' and spacing

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the following to the scripts part of the `package.json`:

```
"ios-15": "react-native run-ios --simulator=`iPhone 15`",
```

and run with the following command:

```
npm run ios-15
```

Comment: As stated earlier I have already tried running the command with --simulator specified and it does not work. Additionally this command results in a syntax error of `sh: iPhone: command not found` but even if it didn't it would result in the same error as before `error No simulator available with name "iPhone 15".`